# Windows Explorer: Increase Size of TIle Layout without changing layout

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I want to change the size of the `Tile View` in Windows Explorer, Specifically in the This PC Section.

Presently the view looks something like this,
[image]

Any attempt to change this immediately destroys the property of being able to see the total space in the drive and the total space occupied. Is there a way to keep this property intact and be able to increase the size of the icons? Preferably without using third party software like Directory Opus or Double Commander, etc.

System Details:
OS: Windows 10
Version: 20H2
Build: 19042

Comment: I don't think so.. "Content", "Tiles ", and "Detail" views all support the property but don't support dynamic resizing.  Perhaps someone knows a hack.. I doubt it but we will see. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to make it work, resize will affect the screen in general tho.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-the-size-of-text-in-windows-10-1d5830c3-eee3-8eaa-836b-abcc37d99b9a

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).